# How to deal with implicit package dependency through required function arguments?

Tags: r

Background:

I am writing a little R package [RHYPE](https://github.com/rcapell/RHYPE) for import/export and visualisation of results from a specific hydrological model (HYPE). 
I just added a map plot function where one argument is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (argument 'data'), i.e. the spatial object to which data is mapped, and another is new data to be attached to the `data` slot of the spatial object and plotted later on (argument 'newdata').

Some simplified code illustrating the relevant parts of the function:

```
PlotMapOutput <- function(newdata, map) {

  # control argument type
  stopifnot(class(map) == "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")

  # add data to map table, 
  # merge by common column (assumed to be index 1 in both tables)
  map@data <- data.frame(map@data, data[match(map@data[, 1], newdata[, 1]), ]) 

  # plot the map
  plot(map, col = map$color, border = NA)
}
```

Here is my question:

By requiring a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, I *implicitly* require users of my function to have packages `sp` and `rgdal` (or another package for importing spatial data) installed and loaded. However, I also *explicitly* use methods from these packages. Do I have to add these packages to the `Imports:` section of the description file? I started to read up on Depends vs. Imports and got confused as to how to write an import of a method, and then stumbled on the implicit requirement.

Thanks for any clarifying comments!

Comment: You could make them dependencies, but only if those packages are absolutely necessary to run your package.  If they're not absolutely necessary, you could also "borrow" the source code of the functions used from the other packages.

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks, in this case, many other functions do not depend on sp at all, so a dependency seems a bit over the top here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add one of the package to  `Imports:` (in your `DESCRIPTION`),
but *additionally* you also need to make good use of the
`NAMESPACE` file, namely with a line

```
importClassesFrom("sp", spatialPolygonsDataFrame)
```

I would use other (good quality!) packages as examples, if the reading about namespaces is too hard.

The `sp` package itself is a good example to learn from.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that sounds reasonable. I use roxygen, so I tried to add this to the function:

`#' @importClassesFrom sp SpatialPolygonsDataFrame SpatialPolygons`
`#' @importMethodsFrom sp plot.SpatialPolygons`

resulting in the following lines in NAMESPACE:

importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialPolygons)
importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialPolygonsDataFrame)
importMethodsFrom(sp,"plot.SpatialPolygons")

However, when building, R comes back with:

`No methods found in "sp" for requests: plot.SpatialPolygons`

Comment: sorry for the garbled layout, I am new here.  
Adding to the previous comment:  
`plot.SpatialPolygons` is not exported from sp, does that mean I cannot import it separately to my package's search path?   
thanks!